# Enable user to send text to specific Gmail contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts-api, gmail-api

In our website, we need to achieve a seemingly simple task: Enable the user to send a specific text to all or some of his/her Gmail contacts (including contact selection).

We don't actually need the contact data itself. We prefer some kind of "Gmail Plugin" (if there is one) that asks the user to login and does all the work. Alas, we couldn't find any.

We did find several different Google APIs related to this task. Some of them seem to give us contacts data. Others seem to handle sending email:

- There is "Contacts API" under
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/...
- There is "Contacts Service" under
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/...
- There is "Gmail Service" under
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/...
- There is "Gmail Platform Integration" under
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/...

Each of the above looks different and there seems to be much overlapping between them.

So what is the recommended method to achieve our original task? Is there a plugin that does it all? If not - should we use separate APIs for getting the contacts data and sending the emails, or are there Google APIs that combine both sub-tasks? In case those are separate tasks - is it possible to email via Gmail, or are there other recommended services for the email sending part?

Comment: Actually there is a bypass by linking to https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&su=My%20subject&body=My%20body - the question is how to "pre-click" the 'To' field in order to display contact selection, or at least tell the user to click it.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question: you must use the first API you pointed, **Contacts API** under https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/.

Basically, you want to use the Google Contacts API with OAuth2 authentication in your website: user will be prompted by Google to allow your website to read user contacts.

First, read a bit about OAuth2 authentication flows here: http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/

Second step: register your app on Google Console and get your key/pass for the Contacts API (you'll need `contacts.readonly` permission): https://console.developers.google.com

Then, as you'll use the `OAuth2 for Web Servers`, check this Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Alternatively, you can use third part libraries to easily import contacts to your website. There are free libraries, like PHP [OpenInviter.org](http://www.openinviter.com), Ruby [OmniAuth gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), and paid alternatives, like [CloudSponge.com](https://www.cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail) (multi-language).

**Disclaimer**: I work for CloudSponge.com.

Comment: If I do gapi.auth.signIn, is it the same like OAuth2 authentication in this respect?

Comment: While it's specific for Google+ JavaScript API, yes, according to Google doc, this method *initiates the client-side Google+ Sign-In **OAuth 2.0** flow*.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this as you say with Google APIs and a Chrome Extension for example.

The user can add a Chrome Extension from the Chrome Webstore.  The Extension will provide the user with a user interface to allow them to compose their message and send to the selected contacts.

The users contacts can be retrieved with the Google Contacts API.

The message can be sent to the selected contacts with the Gmail API.

There is a lot of documentation and examples for all of the above which together will give you what you want.

Depending on how much use this is going to get, you could use a contextual gadget which is browser agnostic - but visible in all emails in Gmail.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong the idea is to post the text to buffer a and submit pointer to array on buffet a and copy it to class b pointer a 0 than release the array and buffer so new allocation can be done